# when equals always return true in the hash table?

Tags: hashtable, equals

What would be the result if we change equals method in hash table such that it always return true?

(hash code is using uses hashcode() of String class)

Comment: How would you change the hash table so that `equals()` always returns true?

Comment: 1.yes this is java. 
2.my question was what would happen if I change like that.